# Calling function pointer inside vector doesn't do anything

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I am currently trying to implement a CHIP-8 emulator. In these emulators, you read the content of a cartridge, which gives you " opcodes ", values corresponding to a function. I don't want to write a huge `switch case` statement to take care of these opcodes (in the context of a CHIP-8 emulator, this is ok since there's not too much opcodes, but in the context of a Gameboy emulator, for example, it can yield some huge `switch case` statements).

My approach is as follows:

I have a struct containing a range for the opcode, the name of the function and a pointer to the function (`void* func`).

```cpp
struct instruction {
    std::pair<uint16_t, uint16_t> range;
    std::string name;
    void* func;

    instruction(std::pair<uint16_t, uint16_t> range, std::string name, void* func) {
        this->range = range;
        this->name = name;
        this->func = func;
    }
};
```

My class looks like this (please d'ont hit me, I've put everything `public` for now but things will move into private when everything's working):

```cpp
class Chip8 {
    public:
        Chip8();
        virtual ~Chip8();

        void set_opcodes(void);

        bool load_cartridge(std::string path);
        void output_cartridge_contents(void);
        bool verifiy_instructions(void);

        void JUMP(void);

        // 0     -> 0x1FF: interpreter (unused since the emulator is running outside of the memory)
        // 0x200 -> 0xE9F: cartridge data
        // 0xEA0 -> 0xEFF: call stack, internal use, and other variables
        // 0xF00 -> 0xFFF: display refresh
        std::vector<uint8_t> memory;
        std::vector<uint8_t> registers;

        // Index register
        uint16_t I;
        // Program counter
        uint16_t pc;

        std::vector<uint8_t> stack;
        // Stack pointer
        uint8_t sp;

        std::vector<instruction> instr;

        // Timers
        uint8_t delay_timer;
        uint8_t sound_timer;

        uint16_t opcode;

        // Screen
        bool gfx[64 * 32];

};
```

Let's take an example function, JUMP

```cpp
void Chip8::JUMP(void) {
    this->pc = (this->opcode & 0x0FFF);
}
```

I'm then filling a vector containing all the implemented opcodes,

```cpp
this->instr.push_back(instruction(std::pair<uint16_t, uint16_t>(0x1000,0x1FFF), std::string("JUMP"), (void*)&Chip8::JUMP))
```

The current opcode is read, then compared to the implemented functions' range (for example, if the opcode is `0x1225`, the JUMP function will be called). When the correct function is found, the following code is called (`i` being the index of the correct `instruction` in the `instr` vector showed above) :

```cpp
this->instr[i].func;
```

But when I do this, nothing happens (i.e. the value of `pc` doesn't change, `std::cout` produce nothing on the console, etc.). I've tried multiple approaches (changing `func` type to `void (*func)(void)`, trying to call `this->instr[i].func();`), but no luck so far. I think I'm missing something here. Anyone has some pointers ?

Thanks

Comment: Is `Chip8::JUMP` a class member function or a function inside a namespace?

Comment: `Chip8::JUMP` is a class member function.

Comment: `(void*)&Chip8::JUMP` is invalid, member pointers do not convert to plain pointers.

Comment: Normal functions can't be portably cast to `void*` (it's a conditionally supported feature). *Non-static member* function can't be safely to `void*` at all. Conceptually, what is `this` when you call `func`?

Comment: Just to be sure that I didn't say anything wrong, I've added the whole class code above. In the context of the struct, `this` is supposed to point to the struct itself. In the context of `this->instr[i].func;`, `this`refers to the object (`Chip8`).

Comment: for sure a func pointer should be void (*func)()) in the arguments of your constructor .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `Chip8::JUMP` is a non static class member function, you need an object of the class to call the function on.  This is because non static member functions have a implicit first parameter of the class type that is used to enable the use of `this` inside the function.

You can solve this by using a `std::function` and using a lambda or `std::bind` to tie the function to an object.  That would look like

```
struct instruction {
    std::pair<uint16_t, uint16_t> range;
    std::string name;
    std::function<void(void)> func;

    template<typename Func>
    instruction(std::pair<uint16_t, uint16_t> range, std::string name, Func func) : range(range), name(name), func(func) {}
};

//...

this->instr.push_back(instruction(std::pair<uint16_t, uint16_t>(0x1000,0x1FFF), std::string("JUMP"), [this]{ this->JUMP(); }))

// and call it like

this->instr[i].func();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, the code still doesn't execute when doing this. Since I'm totally new to `std::function`, I can't find any reason why it isn't working. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: @Coulis You also need `this->instr[i].func();` since `this->instr[i].func;` doesn't actually call the function.

Comment: Thank you so much! Indeed, I missed the parenthesis. Thank you for your detailed answer about the implicit first parameter, I'll look into it to fully grasp the concept!

Answer (score 1):

> pointer to the function (`void* func`).

`void *` is not a pointer to a function. It is a pointer to an object.

> ```
> (void*)&Chip8::JUMP
> ```

This is a bad cast.  A member function pointer cannot be meaningfully converted to `void*`. Indirecting through the converted pointer would have undefined behaviour (even if converted back to the correct type).

> ```
> this->instr[i].func;
> ```
>
> But when I do this, nothing happens

`this->instr[i].func;` is not a function call expression. This is an id-expression. Id-expressions don't have side-effects.

All function call expressions have parentheses that contain the (possibly empty) parameter list.

> I've tried multiple approaches (changing `func` type to `void (*func)(void)`

`void (*func)(void)` *is* a function pointer. But it is not a member function pointer. You cannot convert `&Chip8::JUMP` to a function pointer.

> trying to call `this->instr[i].func()`;

This is a function call expression, so you're getting closer. This would be the correct syntax for a function pointer, but you've attempted to use a non-static member function, so a function pointer doesn't work for you.

---

You could possibly make `instruction` into a template, and use member function pointers:

```
template<class T>
struct instruction {
    void (T::*func)(); // a pointer to member function
    // ...
};

// insert
instr.emplace_back(/* other member initializers */, &JUMP);

// call
(this->*(instr[i].func))()
```